# reversing enrichment routine

Tags: arm64, aarch64

I want to know where a specific `std::string` comes from, find the enrichment routine in the `C++` application I'm reversing.

The variable I'm looking for it at @ `[X21,#8]`, I don't fully understand the following code, is that @ `*(*off_1B2000) + 8)` ?  ( off_1B2000.readPointer().add(8).readPointer() ? )

Do I need to look for who sets the global pointer `off_1B2000` ?

Is that an inline constructor ?

Let's assume I break in the start routine, I want to know where to set write **watchpoint** to figure out who writes to `*(x21+8)`
do I set @ `*(*off_1B2000) + 8)` ?

```
loc_9F0000
ADRP            X0, #off_1B2000@PAGE
ADD             X21, SP, #0x260+v1
ADD             X24, SP, #0x260+v1
MOV             X8, X24
LDR             X0, [X0,#off_1B2000@PAGEOFF]
STR             XZR, [X21,#0x50]
ADD             X0, X0, #0x18
STR             X0, [X21]
STR             X0, [X21,#8] // <<  *(x21+8)=x0 This is who I'm looking for
STR             X0, [X21,#0x10]
STR             X0, [X21,#0x18]
STR             X0, [X21,#0x20]
STR             X0, [X21,#0x28]
STR             X0, [X21,#0x30]
STR             X0, [X21,#0x38]
STR             X0, [X21,#0x40]
MOV             W0, #0xFFFFFFFF
STR             W0, [X21,#0x48]
MOV             W0, #1
STR             W0, [X21,#0x4C]
MOV             X0, X19
STR             WZR, [X21,#0x58]
STR             WZR, [X21,#0x5C]
STRB            WZR, [X21,#0x60]
BL              sub_9F7000
```

Comment: What exactly is "enrichment routine"? I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: Terminology; for example, `person_id` to `Person` object -> enrichment. Some routine takes an `id` and I want to figure out where the enrichment takes place, find the query to the DB (not the case, or might be.. statically compiled)

Comment: so it's just a weird term for "lookup"?

Answer (score 1):

This `STR` operation adds 8 bytes to the offset at X21, then stores the value of X0 there.

You are working with QWORD sized variables (8), so in C code it is something like:

`(uint64_t *)(offset_at_X21 + 1) = X0`

Edit:

The first instruction sets `X0=address of off_1B2000` (const 0x1B2000). Later it is dereferenced `[X0,#offset...]`. This is *(0x1B2000+0x1B2000), which is odd. Could it be `LDR X0,[X0]`? IDA may give it the name "#off_1B2000" because it is clear that this is the value.

X21 pointes to the variable "v1" on the stack, (set by `ADD X21,SP,#0x260+v1`).

The result of the code is something like this:

`[v1+8] = *(off_1B2000)`

Comment: That I understood, please explain the relation to `off_1B2000`

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks but where do I set the watchpoint ?

Comment: The watchpoint is on write to `off_1B2000`. And yes it looks like a constructor of a class instance, pointed to by `v1` on the stack. The v1+8 is the second QWORD of the class.